# Custom Linux mint installation: Is there a way to add files to a bootable linux mint 19 USB such that they are copied to the desktop on installation?

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

Apologies if my question is strange. I couldn't find anyother questions similar to this, so was unable to find an answer. I would like to know whether it is possible to copy a set of files onto a bootable linux mint USB, and have them on fresh installation (from the USB) be displayed on the desktop. It would greatly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Mint installer but it looks like preseeding is used.

Preseeding is helpful for unattended installations, for instance with Debian, and many of its derivatives, you can use [`preseed/late_command` to run any shell command you want](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs05.en.html#preseed-hooks) (and copy files from bootable to install target).

You probably need to customize your bootable media to launch the install right away instead of starting a live session.